# Request JSON by AJAX in two ways

Tags: javascript, ajax

I don't know why but when I do request JSON in this way console log prints nothing:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function elenco_studenti() {
    var url = "/controller?action=student_list";
    xhr.responseType = 'text';
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = print();
    xhr.send(null);
}
function print(){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Instead when I do request JSON in this way, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller?action=student_list',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 4):

Assign the function reference instead of invoking the function

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = print();
```

to

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = print;
```

and wait for the actual response to be ready

```
function print() {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
     console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
}
```

link to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)